# Notifying parent when particular property of Struct is mutated, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, struct

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
struct InputField{
    var input: String{
        didSet{
            if let onChangeValue =  onValueChange{
                onChangeValue()
            }
            if let errorMsgAfterValidation = errorMsgAfterValidation{
                self.errorMsg = errorMsgAfterValidation()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var errorMsg: String = ""
    var onValueChange: (() -> ())?
    var errorMsgAfterValidation: (() -> (String))?
}

class FormViewModel{
    init() {
        self.nameInputField = InputField(input: "")
        self.setupFormFields()
    }
    
    var nameInputField: InputField
    
    func setupFormFields(){
        self.nameInputField.onValueChange = {
            //Custom cross felds Logic, ex: Load Name suggestions
        }
        self.nameInputField.errorMsgAfterValidation = {
            //Form field validation
            // ISSUE: self.nameInputField.input is not the latest one
            return validateName(self.nameInputField.input)
        }
    }
}
```

Here 'input' gets mutated as user types in text field.

ISSUE: inside closures self.nameInputField instance/value is not the latest one. It's one mutation behind. If I pass 'self' as a closure parameter then its not equivalent to self.nameInputeField that parent FormViewModel is holding.

didSet on nameInputField gets called after closure is executed.

What I Want: My input field will notify FormViewModel and ask for error msgs. FormViewModel should be in proper sync with input field. Also I can't use class due to some other reasons.

One solution is to remove both the closures and move logic in them to didSet of nameInputField, but I have like 10 odd fields and that doesnn't look great.

Answer (score 0):

#### Value Types Are Always Immutable.

It is easier to understand with `Int`.

```swift
class A {
    var value: Int = 1 {
        didSet {
            print("value changed", oldValue, value)
        }
    }
}

let a = A()
a.value = 2
// prints "value changed 1 2"
```

Even if `value` is "mutable" by using `var`, it is not. Each time you modify `value`, swift generates a new `Int` and replace `value` with it. Your `didSet` observer is called after this replacement completes.

Structs are a little more confusing but they are value types too.

```swift
struct S {
    
    var value: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print("value changed", oldValue, value)
        }
    }
}

class A {
    
    var s: S = S() {
        didSet {
            print("s changed", oldValue, s)
        }
    }
}

let a = A()
a.s.value = "hi"
// prints "value changed  hi"
// prints "s changed S(value: "") S(value: "hi")"
```

1. Any property changes of a struct would cause the struct itself being replaced by a new one (copied from it with the updated property).
2. It happens in the following sequence:

   1. property is changed
   2. property `didSet` observer is called
   3. struct is changed
   4. struct `didSet` observer is called

So in the step 2, where your `errorMsgAfterValidation` is being executed, the struct itself has not even being updated yet. This is why "It's one mutation behind".

In fact, your code causes a runtime exception in a Xcode playground I just created.

```
imultaneous accesses to 0x600003898ab0, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at  (0x105563ff4).
Current access (a read) started at:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00007fff2ff7be50 swift_beginAccess + 568
6    MyPlayground                       0x00000001045de150 main + 0
7    CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff20390114 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
8    CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff2038f382 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 434
9    CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff20389bc1 __CFRunLoopRun + 899
10   CoreFoundation                     0x00007fff2038949f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
11   GraphicsServices                   0x00007fff2c257d28 GSEventRunModal + 139
12   UIKitCore                          0x00007fff24696967 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
13   UIKitCore                          0x00007fff2469bb43 UIApplicationMain + 101
14   MyPlayground                       0x00000001045de150 main + 194
15   libdyld.dylib                      0x00007fff2025a3e8 start + 1
Fatal access conflict detected.
```

To quickly solve your problem, modify your `errorMsgAfterValidation` to accept a `String` parameter, and pass the current `input` to it so that you don't reference `self.nameInputField` in this closure.

```swift
struct InputField{
    var input: String{
        didSet{
            if let onChangeValue =  onValueChange{
                onChangeValue()
            }
            if let errorMsgAfterValidation = errorMsgAfterValidation{
                self.errorMsg = errorMsgAfterValidation(input)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var errorMsg: String = ""
    var onValueChange: (() -> ())?
    var errorMsgAfterValidation: ((String) -> (String))?
}

class FormViewModel{
    init() {
        self.nameInputField = InputField(input: "")
        self.setupFormFields()
    }
    
    var nameInputField: InputField
    
    func setupFormFields(){
        self.nameInputField.onValueChange = {
            //Custom cross felds Logic, ex: Load Name suggestions
        }
        self.nameInputField.errorMsgAfterValidation = { input in
            return validateName(input)
        }
    }
}
```

Without more information, it is hard to give a better solution.

Comment: This is basically what I deduced when I faced this issue. But thing is I may need whole struct's access in errorMsgAfterValidation. I may want chnage other properties inside that closure. I can pass in 'self' in closure but then, I don't think holding outdated struct is safe/good practice. What I endee up doing is, make a protocol "NestedMutableStruct" with a method onMutate(oldValue: Self) which will get called from didSet of the struct. This method will call closures.

Comment: Aditional context: I will have a form with multiple sections having multiple fields. Both section and fields are struct based models. I want call backs when any 'input' of any field in any section is changed, and then handle them accordingly.